# Check if a popup is being opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

*Problem:*
Hi, I am giving a sensitive service to my customers. However some of my customers are opening advertisement popups (using JavaScript) on their pages that my service is included, which is creating problems for us.

My service to these customers includes a **.js** filed included on their websites **(this js file is hosted on my server)**.

*What I need:*

1. Is there a way I could add some functionality to my js file to stop functioning if the page which it is included in, tries to open a popup?
2. If number 1 is not possible, is it possible to stop any popups from being opened?

*(Don't need a solution based on browser addons and similar things...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop functioning popup (stop opening) in a page by including the code shown below in a .js file or in the page directly. This code should be included globally before execution of actual window.showModalDialog() or window.open().

For dialog:

```
window.showModalDialog = function () {};
```

or

New window:

```
window.open = function () {};
```

Above implementation overrides window.showModalDialog() or window.open() functionalities.

Comment: I mean a window.open() javascript popup not a modal window.

Comment: Same applicable for window.open() too.